# clusterProperties in mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want to draw clusters on my map but not with number of points inside the text-field

```
map.addLayer({
        id: 'cluster-count',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'stations',
        filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
        layout: {
            'text-field': '{point_count}',
            //'text-field': ['number-format', ['get', {point_count}]],
            'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-size': 12
        }
    });
```

but with %.

Something like that:
`{point_count / overall_number_of_points}`

But I can't find any example of that thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [Math expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#math) for Mapbox:

```
["/", number, number]: number
["%", number, number]: number
```

In your case it could be something like this..

```
["%", ['get', 'point_count'], ['get', 'overall_number_of_points']]
```